Powershell Post Request Failing
I'm trying to turn a standard curl request into something that can be run in a powershell script.
Here's the curl that works consistently:
curl -X POST -F "file=@C:\your\file\location\Example.csv" -H "Authorization: Bearer [INSERT BEARER TOKEN]" https://example-api-or-endpoint.com
Here's the powershell that consistently fails:
$uri = "https://example-api-or-endpoint.com" $outputCsvPath = "C:\your\file\location\Example.csv" $headers = @{"Authorization" = "Bearer [BEARERTOKEN]"} Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $uri -Method Post -InFile $outputCsvPath -ContentType "multipart/form-data" -Headers $headers
Expected Result:
{"file_id":"FILEID","message":"File sent successfully","status":"success"}
Actual Result:
{"message":"No file part in the request","status":"error"}
I've tried using RestMethod, changing InFile to Body, made sure the file path is correct and the file exists, and I keep getting an error saying that there isn't a file part in the request.
It's worth mentioning that the URL I'm using is a Google Cloud Function endpoint, so not quite an API but the CURL statement I mentioned in the details works 100% of the time but the powershell version of it fails 100% of the time.
For some additional context, the POST request should be sending the entire file, not it's contents.

I think the issue is the encoding being used with the -F option.  See Curl manual : https://curl.se/docs/manpage.html#:~:text=The%20following%20options%20are%20global,and%20%2Dv%2C%20%2D%2Dverbose.   I think the solution for PS to work is to include the Content-Type.


Note:

The solution below applies to PowerShell (Core) 7 only.

Since you have a working curl command, you could simply use it  from PowerShell, now that curl.exe ships with Windows - just be sure to invoke it as curl.exe from Windows PowerShell, as curl is unfortunately otherwise interpreted as the built-in alias of Invoke-WebRequest.



Example 6 in the Invoke-WebRequest help topic shows a simplified multipart/form-data submission, passing a hashtable to the -Form parameter with an entry whose value is a [System.IO.FileInfo] instance, as obtained via Get-Item, for instance:
Therefore:
$uri = "https://example-api-or-endpoint.com"
$outputCsvPath = "C:\your\file\location\Example.csv"
$headers = @{ "Authorization" = "Bearer [BEARERTOKEN]" } 

# Use the -Form parameter with a hashtable and add an entry that
# references the file to upload via Get-Item 
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $uri -Method Post -Headers $headers -Form @{
  file = Get-Item -LiteralPath $outputCsvPath
}

Note:

With this simplified approach, you don't get to control the media type of the file being uploaded; the generic application/octet-stream is invariably used.

If you need more fine-grained control, you'll need to use .NET APIs directly: see Example 5



That didn't work, I got this error
Invoke-WebRequest : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'Form'.
At line:7 char:60

Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $uri -Method Post -Headers $headers -Form @{

                                                       ~~~~~


CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Invoke-WebRequest], ParameterBindingException
FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeWebRequestCommand




Idk the most recent version but here's mine:
PSVersion 5.1.22621.3810

@SephRodriguez, yes, unfortunately, the -Form parameter is only available in PowerShell (Core) 7, wheras you're using Windows PowerShell. You could consider sticking with your curl command; to make it work in Windows PowerShell, invoke it as curl.exe, otherwise curl is interpreted as the built-in alias of Invoke-WebRequest.

@PeterSmith Thank you. I hate that the only difference is .exe :/
Regardless, that helps a ton.
